# Heredoc with backslash

Tags: bash, heredoc

What is the difference between

```
cat >test.txt <<\EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

and

```
cat >test2.txt << EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

I'm writing a ANTLR based syntax coloring and the `\` after the `<<` irritates me (found in an example file). What does it mean? Can I ignore it for syntax coloring like a `-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [POSIX standard on here-document syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

> If any part of *word* [the thing after `<<` - GD] is quoted, the
> delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on *word*, and
> the here-document lines shall not be expanded. Otherwise, the
> delimiter shall be the *word* itself.

So... do you color shell expansions inside here-documents? That is, in something like this:

```
cat >test2.txt << EOF
hello $somevar
world $(somecommand)
EOF
```

Do you color `$somevar` and `$(somecommand)` as variable and command expansions respectively? If so, you need to disable that if the delimiter word is quoted or escaped.